# pointer is changing its address after a function call

Tags: c++

I have a question about this portion of code:

```
const float *dest = (float*)varPtr1.memoryPointer;
float temp; 
ReadFromMemory(temp);
.
.
continue the rest of treatment with 'dest' and 'temp'
```

Everything works fine and when reaching the second line the 'dest' have the correct value, but, after calling the function **ReadFromMemory()**, the 'dest' pointer changes its address to 0x100000000 and of course its value becomes wrong (pointing to another address).

So my question is, why the 'dest' changes its target after calling the func although its already not available out of this scope.

NB: temp is correct

```
template<typename T>
void myClass:: ReadFromMemory(T &var, int var_pos)
{
    if(cons64requested)
    {
        cons64requested = false;
    }
    else
    {
        if(var_pos==2)
        {
            const4NextInstruction = snd_param;
        }
        else
        {
            const4NextInstruction = fst_param;
        }
    }
    memcpy(&var,&const4NextInstruction,0x8);
}
```

Comment: What is the definition of `ReadFromMemory`? Does it interfere with `dest` in any way?

Comment: You need to provide more information, such as an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). How are you checking that `dest`'s value changes?

Comment: hello brothers,
i edited the question and i added 'ReadFromMemory' definition

Comment: @MohamedElleuch Please post real, compilable code. The `ReadFromMemory` you added has two arguments vs. the `ReadFromMemory` that gets called with only one argument, `const4NextInstruction` is not defined etc.

Comment: going to guess that `0x8` should be `0x4`

Comment: @dxiv The function definition in the header is like that: void ReadFromMemory(T &var, int var_pos = 2); and the const4NextInstruction is global quint64 variable

Comment: @kmdreko or better yet, `sizeof var`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this problem is to not pass temp as reference, instead, i pass its pointer.
So the function declaration becomes like following:

```
void myClass:: ReadFromMemory(T *var, int var_pos)
```

Comment: Your issue has nothing to do with how you pass the parameter: you're trying to `memcpy` 8 bytes into a `float` that is probably only 4 bytes, corrupting whatever is next to it and triggering UB.